# Error in WSFC Role while applying SQL 2016 CU7 in Multiple SQL instance environment

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, clustering

Kindly advise on following error:

> Cluster resource 'AG1_NAME' of type 'SQL Server Availability Group' in clustered role 'AG1_NAME' failed
>
> Based on the failure policies for the resource and role, the cluster service may try to bring the resource online on this node or move the group to another node of the cluster and then restart it.  Check the resource and group state using Failover Cluster Manager or the Get-ClusterResource Windows PowerShell cmdlet.

Environment:

> AG1: (Primary = SRV01\DEV1, Secondary= SRV02\DEV1, SRV03\DEV1)
> AG2: (Primary = SRV02\DEV2, Secondary= SRV03\DEV2, SRV01\DEV2)

The error occurred while updating AG2 Replicas with SQL SERVER 2016 SP2 CU7 which was SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU4.

Updating order as follows, and there was no error during the update wizard

> 1. Set fail-over to manual on **SRV01\DEV2**
> 2. Updated **SRV01\DEV2**   -- *Noticed WSFC error (above mentioned)*
> 3. Set fail-over mode to Auto on **SRV01\DEV2**
> 4. Set fail-over mode to manual on **SRV03\DEV2**
> 5. Updated **SRV03\DEV2**
> 6. Set fail-over mode to Auto on **SRV03\DEV2**
> 7. Manually Fail-over from **SRV02\DEV2** (Primary) to **SRV03\DEV2**
> 8. Updated **SRV02\DEV2**
> 9. Manually Fail-back to **SRV02\DEV2** (Primary) from **SRV03\DEV2**

Is it normal while updating 2nd instance of SQL Server the 1st instance get interrupted while server involved in Availability Groups, or should we follow any particular method in this case to avoid any error as such.

Fortunately, particular **AG1** and all resources of WSFC was working normal when i look back immediately (after the error) into Roles page of WSFC manager. also PowerShell  `Get-ClusterResource`. but i'm concerned about production update and future updates. Any suggestions would be appreciable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again @SeanGallardy, i have been tried re-produce the issue, unfortunately it's not occurred again. i look back SQL Error log and cluster log carefully, i realized missed one line `The availability group is being asked to stop the lease renewal. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.` It seems like co-incident not due to patch update, not sure what was exact reason, discovered from [MS blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alwaysonpro/2014/11/26/diagnose-unexpected-failover-or-availability-group-in-resolving-state/), it might be with High CPU utilization, memory pressure or lot of IO requests in particular moment.

Increasing resource lease time would be work-around solution in my-case as it was DEV environment.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it normal while updating 2nd instance of SQL Server the 1st instance get interrupted while server involved in Availability Groups, or should we follow any particular method in this case to avoid any error as such.

No, it's not expected. The error, though, says it tried to bring the resource online and failed at least 3 times (by default, unless you changed this value). This leads me to believe that the instance was patched while it was a primary, which would of course fail while the service is offline for patching. If it wasn't a primary then you'll need to look into the SQL Server errorlog and the cluster log to understand what had happened.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, when i looked at SQL Error Log it just indicating that **_it's being asked by WSFC to do so_  and read WSFC log for more details**, But WSFC Log doesn't show any details on this cause. i think, i have to re-produce the error by changing **VerboseLogging** option at WSFC

Comment: @ShekarKola Depending on the version of Windows Server, you already have verbose logging (Debug, level 5). Regardless you should see a reason why the clustered resource is taken offline, that's what you need to follow up on. The cluster log itself isn't going to directly come out and tell you in one line.